# "No subject alternative DNS name matching <api.hostname.net> found" Error when using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-boot, ssl

I've been trying to send RestTemplate requests to an API url that looks as follows:

`https://api.something.hostname.net/api/key=key&parameter1=val1&etc`

which was supposed to return a JSON response. But it would give the following error:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <api.something.hostname.net> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [sni-required.hostname.com]`

I would then implement my own RestTemplate as follows (from this [link](https://memorynotfound.com/ignore-certificate-errors-apache-httpclient/)):

```
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, CertificateException {


        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        requestFactory.setHttpClient(createAcceptSelfSignedCertificateClient());

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);


        return restTemplate;
    }


    private static CloseableHttpClient createAcceptSelfSignedCertificateClient()
            throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {

        // use the TrustSelfSignedStrategy to allow Self Signed Certificates
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .loadTrustMaterial(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();

        // we can optionally disable hostname verification.
        // if you don't want to further weaken the security, you don't have to include this.
        HostnameVerifier allowAllHosts = new NoopHostnameVerifier();

        // create an SSL Socket Factory to use the SSLContext with the trust self signed certificate strategy
        // and allow all hosts verifier.
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory connectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, allowAllHosts);

        // finally create the HttpClient using HttpClient factory methods and assign the ssl socket factory
        return HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(connectionFactory)
                .build();
    }
```

And now it throws:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching api.rasp.yandex.net found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:214) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

The [link](https://memorynotfound.com/ignore-certificate-errors-apache-httpclient/) example makes a successful request using HttpClient. Can I solve the issue for RestTemplate or do I have to move onto HttpClient?

How do I disable SSL checks for the time being in the development stage? Is this a problem that can be solved locally or is it the certificate issue of the API provider?

Comment: The solution can be found in this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34841989

Comment: Thanks @charles_chung, I'll take a look at it a bit later. But for the time being I've found a solution. The problem was somehow related to Spring Boot. Making a single restTemplate request to the required URL at the start of the application strangely solves the issue